# what is the correct terminology

Tags: verbs

If you are sitting in traffic and you know it is because of an accident.  Do you say;
there is an accident ahead
or 
there is an accident in front

Comment: Your subject title is not very descriptive, and would apply to too many questions here to be useful.  Please [edit] to make it more specific.

Comment: *Why* are you saying this?  Talking to yourself?  Talking to someone else in the car who cannot see ahead?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a social interaction, there is likely to be many ways of expressing it.

For example, my choice in British English would be:

> There is an accident up ahead.

However, it also depends on the context, because if we heard about the accident on the radio we might say:

> There is an accident ahead.

For your other example 'There is an accident in front' the response might be 'in front of what?'